# Не работает проверка нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android-studio, android-button, action, ontouchlistener

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку, которая работает лишь при нажатии и удерживании её: если нажать и отвести палец от кнопки в другую область, она перестанет работать, а если 
нажать в другую область и, удерживая палец, навести его на кнопку, то она будет работать. На *ru.stackoverflow.com* не помогли, на *stackoverflow.com* один пользователь ответил и написал onTouchListener:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if(v.getLeft()<=event.getX() && v.getRight()>=event.getX() && v.getTop()<=event.getY() && v.getBottom()>=event.getY()) {
                   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                       Log.d("LOG", "pressed");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                       Log.d("LOG", "released");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                       Log.d("LOG", "moving");
               }
               else
               {
                   Log.d("LOG", "out of area");
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
```

Я попробовал этот код, но он не сработал: [Скрин кода](http://prntscr.com/oh7nvb)
[Логи](http://prntscr.com/oh7re6)

К слову, если не использовать это проверку `if(v.getLeft()<=event.getX() && v.getRight()>=event.getX() && v.getTop()<=event.getY() && v.getBottom()>=event.getY()) {`, то кнопка работает, но не так как нужно (просто нажимается и всё, без проверки находится ли палец в области действия кнопки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, проблема предложенного условия в том, что они может никогда не выполнятся, так как getX/getY для event возвращает координаты клика относительно View, а не глобальные. А getRigth и т.п. дают глобальные. То есть или надо заменить getX/getY на getRawX/getRawY, которые вернут глобальные координаты, либо заменить getRigth/getTop/getLeft/getBottom на 0/0/getWidth/getHeght

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Пришлось самую малость подумать, чтобы всё заработало

Comment: Рабочая проверка: [http://prntscr.com/oi2s4o]